# Why did a show up in my table name?

Tags: r, function, attributes

I ran this in **R**:

```
a <- factor(c("A","A","B","A","B","B","C","A","C"))
```

And then I made a table

```
results <- table(a)
```

but when I run

```
> attributes(results)
$dim
[1] 3

$dimnames
$dimnames$a
```

But I'm confused why does `a` show up in my attributes? I've programmed in Java before and I thought variable names weren't supposed to show up in your functions .

Comment: You're missing some code here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I'm not. screenshot proof: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yqflx8u5fb936q/Screenshot%202014-06-08%2022.36.49.png

Comment: Toto, I don't think we're in Java anymore.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer now, but (1) Look at source code for `table()`. (2) Note the internally defined function `list.names`, and it's somewhat subtle use as the default argument for `dnn`. (3) Play with increasing `deparse.level`.

Comment: did you mean "my previous programming experience has been in Java"? The way you phrased that, it sounds like you mean that you're presenting Java code here (which is obviously not true, but has confused some readers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R functions can not only see the data you pass to them, but they can see the actual call that was run to invoke them. So when you run, `table(a)` the `table()` function not only sees the values of `a`, but is also can see that those values came from a variable named `a`.

So by default `table()` likes to name each dimension in the resulting table. If you don't pass explicit names in the call via the `dnn=` parameter, `table()` will look back to the call, and turn the variable name into a character and use that value for the dimension name.

So after `table()` has ran, it has no direct connection to the variable `a`, it merely used the name of that variable as a character label of the results.

Many functions in R do this. For example this is similar to how `plot(height~weight, data=data.frame(height=runif(10), weight=runif(10)))` knows to use the names "weight" and "height" for the axis labels on the plot.

Here's a simple example to show one way this can be accomplished.

```
paramnames <- function(...) {
    as.character(substitute(...()))
}
paramnames(a,b,x)
# [1] "a" "b" "x"
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the only answer is because the designers wanted it that way. It seems reasonable to label table objects with the names of variables that formed the margins:

```
> b <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2, 3,3,3)
> table(a, b)
   b
a   1 2 3
  A 2 1 1
  B 1 2 0
  C 0 0 2
```

R was intended as a clone of S, and S was intended as a tool for working statisticians. R also has a handy function for working with table objects, `as.data.frame`:

```
> as.data.frame(results)
  a Freq
1 A    4
2 B    3
3 C    2
```

If you want to build a function that performs the same sort of labeling or that otherwise retrieves the name of the object passed to your function then there is the `deparse(substitute(.))`-maneuver:

```
 myfunc <- function(x) { nam <- deparse(substitute(x)); print(nam)}

>  myfunc <- function(x) { nam <- deparse(substitute(x)); print(nam)}
> myfunc(z)
[1] "z"
> str(z)
Error in str(z) : object 'z' not found
```

So "z" doesn't even need to exist. Highly "irregular" if you ask me. If you "ask" `myfunc` what its argument list looks like you get the expected answer:

```
> formals(myfunc)
$x
```

But that is a list with an R-name for its single element `x`. R names are language elements, whereas the `names` function will retrieve it as a character value, "x", which is not a language element:

```
> names(formals(myfunc))
[1] "x"
```

R has some of the aspects of Lisp (interpreted, functional (usually))  although the dividing line between its language functions and the data objects seems less porous to me, but I'm not particularly proficient in Lisp.